# What is the proper way to have a ListView show a LINQ query and update dynamically?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and C#, so apologies in advance for any mistakes I make.

In my app, I have a list of plants. When a plant is selected, I have a detail view of info about the plant. In the detail view, I have a button that adds or removes the plant from a shopping list.

To implement this, I have a class named MyPlant, with a field called InCart, and a method ToggleInCart that the button calls. 
(note that I didn't paste in some code to simplify this question as much as possible)

```
public class MyPlant : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    string name;
    bool inCart;
    ...
    public bool InCart
            {
                set
                {
                    if (inCart != value)
                    {
                        inCart = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("InCart");
                    }
                }
                get { return inCart; }
            }

    public ICommand ToggleCartStatus
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_toggleCartStatus == null)
                    {
                        _toggleCartStatus = new Command(() => InCart = !InCart);
                    }
                    return _toggleCartStatus;
                }
```

I have another class called PlantList, which has a method PlantsInCart that uses LINQ to return an ObservableCollection of MyPlant where InCart is true.

```
public class PlantList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection PlantsInCart
    {
        private set { }
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection list = new ObservableCollection(myPlants.Where(i => i.InCart));
            return list;
        }
    }
```

In my XAML, I have a ListView bound to PlantsInCart.

Everything works as I want EXCEPT when I remove the selected plant, the list doesn't update to show the plant is missing even though the data underneath it is correctly updated. If I refresh the list by going to a different page and coming back, then the list shows the right plants.

I suspect this doesn't work because the change in the InCart field isn't bubbling up high enough to that the ListView hears that it is supposed to update.

Can anybody advise me on the proper way to implement this kind of feature? In other words, how should you implement a scenario where you have a list that should update when a property of an item in the list changes?

Comment: you are creating a new instance of your ObservableCollection every time instead of just updating the existing instance

Comment: By the way, thanks for the answer. It was helpful in debugging the problem.